# Deleting rows from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to delete rows from two different tables at the same time. The tables look something like this:

```
TABLE - Value
-----------
ID
Field
<some other stuff...>

TABLE - Srch
-----------
Value_ID
Srch_ID
<some other stuff...>
```

I'm trying to delete all the rows from `VALUE` where `field` is equal to 'SUCCESS' and also delete the rows from `SRCH` that are linked to `VALUE` through `value_id`. In `SRCH` there can be multiple rows with the same `value_id`.

What would this SQL statement look like?

Comment: I'd say you have 3 options.  1) Trigger which does the delete on the other table for you 2) foreign keys between tables and use on delete cascade 3) Delete though a procedure/package where you can control the actions taken. Each has their own pros and cons.  For example the cascade will ALWAYS happen.  A trigger can can exude some control over when it occurs incase certain business rules demand you keep the child, a package/procedure is only good when called so things not calling it will not delete the child; but this offers you the greatest flexibility.

Comment: Ideally, answers should be used to answer questions, not comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While changing the database to do this automatically is ideal, if this is always the behavior you want, and you have permissions on the database to do so.

Otherwise, especially if this is a one time or occasional thing, it can be done in a set of 2 simple queries, run together:

```
Delete from Srch where value_id in (Select ID from value where field='SUCCESS')
Delete from value where field='SUCCESS'
```

If this is a live system, you want to run these as part of a single transaction, so that you don't have values updated in between the two statements, and leave orphans, or something similar. If run with the correct isolation level, this will be your easiest, simplest way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using foreign keys between your 2 tables and `ON DELETE CASCADE`. So you just have to delete the row in Value and all the corresponding rows in Srch will be deleted.

You can add the following constraint to your database:

```
ALTER TABLE Srch ADD CONSTRAINT
FK_Value_ID FOREIGN KEY(Value_ID)
REFERENCES Value (ID) 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Just to be clear (quote from xQbert comment): "the cascade will ALWAYS happen" when an ID from Value is deleted.

Comment: This would work. Your other option would be two delete statements as part of the same transaction. `DELETE FROM SRCH where value_id = :x; DELETE FROM VALUE where value_id = :x;` On an error, just rollback the transaction.

Comment: If the user has permissions to do so, which they may not. Also, this would need to be desired always, and triggers on a database where people (or even programs) have access to alter data should be viewed with extreme caution!

Answer (score 0):

Or a more complex solution Using PL/SQL but no foreign key:

```
DEFINE 
v_success_count number;
v_val_id number;
BEGIN

SELECT INTO v_success_count count(*) FROM


WHILE (select count(*) FROM value WHERE field = 'SUCCESS') > 0
LOOP
    SELECT value_id INTO val_id FROM value WHERE field = 'SUCCESS' AND rownum = 1;

    DELETE FROM srch WHERE value_id = v_val_id;

    DELETE FROM value WHERE field = 'SUCCESS' AND rownum = 1;
END LOOP
COMMIT;
END;
```